# Can anyone explain to me what does the "if not x%2:" mean?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to understand this code but the "if not x%2:" is quite confusing. It has the same result as "if x==2".

```
count_even = 0
for x in range(1,9):
    if not x % 2:
         count_even+=1
```

Comment: its the same as `if  {remainder of x/2} == 0`

Comment: in your case it means everything that is divisible by 2

Comment: `not 0 == True`

Comment: Can you explain to me the "if not x%2:" verbally? I know it is same as some other functions but I want to know how does it work

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python % operator", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  AMong other things, you'll see that it does *not* have the same result as `if x==2`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the same, the first statement is a evaluating if `x` is odd. Why? In python `0` evaluates to `False` and the `%` operator is module, that returns the quotient of the two items.

In the second approach you are just saying if `x` is equal to 2

Answer (score 1):

`x%2` will return 0 when x is even and 1 when x is odd.

So this `if` statement evaluates to `true` when x is even and `false` when x is odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not x%2
```

*Modulo operator* calculates the remainder of number *x* w.r.t number *y*.
And in your example *x* is ranging from 1-9 and *y* is given as 2.

So first,  `x%2` will evaluate to either 1 or 0 based whether x is odd number or even number respectively.

**for example:**

for x=1 , x%2 = 1%2 (calculating the remainder) = **1**

for x=2 , x%2 = 2%2 = **0**

Similarly,
x=3, 3%2 = **1** (remainder)

And so on...

Now, if it is even number meaning evaluating to **0** which is equivalent to **False** and then **`not`** operator is negating the result i.e. **`not(False) == True`**,hence condition becoming  **`True`**

So, when if condition is coming out to be **`True`** then, your code is incrementing the count of even number.

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score -1):

#Hai let me give you one example you can get clarify your doubt !!!

```py
event_squares=[]

for x in range(10):
    if  x%2:  # here conditions True means x is odd(1%2=1(True),3%2=1(True)
        event_squares.append(x*x)

print(event_squares)
```

> output=[1, 9, 25, 49, 81, 1, 9, 25, 49, 81]

```py
event_squares=[]

for x in range(10):
    if not x%2:# means not True=False;0%2=0(False),2%2=0(False) 
        event_squares.append(x*x)

print(event_squares)
```

> output=[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]

```py
#list comprehension way 
event_squaes=[x*x for x in range(10) if not x%2]

print(event_squares)
```

> output=[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]